# how to find memory objects using immunity debugger

Tags: debugging, immunity-debugger, shellcode

I am trying to exploit a program where I have to reuse a socket.

`recv` looks like this:

```
int recv(
_In_  SOCKET s, // socket ID
_Out_ char   *buf,
_In_  int    len,
_In_  int    flags
);
```

I want to find where the socket ID is on the stack. How do I find this using Immunity Debugger?

Comment: @DominikAntal please consider making an answer from your comment since it may answer OP's question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a INT3 (F2) breakpoint on the `recv` function (To jump to that function, hit CTRL+G then type `recv` to the textbox which just appeared, and then hit enter) within Immunity Debugger, and observe the stack (lower right corner) for the socket ID when the breakpoint is hit.